# How do I print the current hostname of a host in ansible

Tags: centos6, configuration-management, ansible

I wrote a role to edit the motd when user log into the machine, but I want to personalize the motd to print the hostname of the machine

What variable do I use? or how do I do this? template? how?
I used the `copy module` for the motd file

So for example I want to be able to say "welcome to $hostname" so how do I parse this hostname using ansible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to use the [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html)-module for this.

Here's an example task:

```
- name: Create motd
  template:
    src: "motd.j2"
    dest: "/etc/motd"
```

The file *motd.j2* (placed in the *templates*-subdirectory of your role) could then look like this:

```
Welcome to host {{ansible_hostname}}!
```

{{ansible_hostname}} will then be replaced with the hostname.

Be sure to "[gather](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) [facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/gather_facts_module.html)" in your role, or else the variable will be empty.

Comment: How do i "gather facts"?..thanks

Comment: works thanks..but what do you mean by "gather facts"?

Comment: I added two links to the documentation for gathering facts.

Comment: what about ip address? can't seem to find that either? how do i grep the ip address? `ansible_ip` ?

Comment: `ansible_eth0.ipv4.address` figured it out after some serious searching..which sucks...ansible should know there are very important variables that should be easier to find and be mentioned clearly on the doc site

Comment: If you search for "ip address" in the ansible docs, you can easily find it in the first link. There's even a [whole paragraph](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-complex-variable-data) that shows two different ways on how to get the address of a host!